# limit execution time and customized error message PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that allows me to upload an image file. I want to limit the execution time to 25s. If the file takes too long to upload, I want to stop the script and output an error message saying "File is taking too long to upload. Please try with a smaller one". I checked out set_time_limit and ini_set('max_execution_time',25) but they don't seem to work (and i don't know how to override phpinfo()). Is there any suggestion for how i should proceed? Anything is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: I couldn't find any better way to fix the execution time without touching the php.ini. So i just use javascript and reload the page after 25s and output an error message. I know it's not the best fix but it's what i have for now. Any other suggestions still welcomed.

Comment: Do you have permission to edit `php.ini`? Are you on shared host? Some of them don't allow you to overwrite php configuration

Comment: I don't have the permission and I would prefer to not change the config. Also, I'd like to output my own error message rather than a Fatal error that comes as a default

Comment: If you don't have permissions you would not be able to use `ini_set` since it might be disabled in php.ini, that's probably because of security reason (normal hosting sites policy)

Comment: Yep, I knew that. That's why i'm asking if there is any other alternative

Comment: I don't think you have many chances unless you get a vps or something that allows you to edit configuration.

Comment: I think it could be done with [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) Using it, you will be able to echo your custom error since you will terminate with process.

Comment: I checked it, looking promising but i don't see any endtime. I want to set the run time to only 25s and then stop...any idea how to use that with Session upload progress??

Comment: For setting custom error message you can use [set_error_handler](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function, all you need to do is to create custom HTML file with style (or without) and callbacks argument for filling the information.

Answer (score 0):

Images are uploaded long times before your PHP Script will start.

You can set the upload time in the `php.ini`. Take a look at [`max_input_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)

But with this you have no possibility to control this (asking the user for a smaller file). Your best bet would be an ajax based upload mechanism.

Comment: can you explain a little more about ajax based upload mechanism? I was thinking of using javascript to check if it receives anything from server within 25s. If not, it will output an error message and stop the uploading but i dont know how to use javascript to stop the php script.

Comment: this is way to broad to handle it here. google on ajax fileupload and you will find hundreds of soultions. Basicly you should combine this with an timer, which cancel it, if it takes longer then 25 secs.